# When i run the spring cloud microservice application through eclipse its working fine but when i use the docker image and try to run then it fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, microservices, spring-cloud

Spring version 2.5.0

I have downloaded the docker image by referring to the below url as shared in github:-

https://github.com/in28minutes/spring-microservices-v2/tree/main/04.docker

I have downloaded the image by running **'docker pull docker.io/in28min/mmv2-currency-exchange-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'** command in my system. The image has been downloaded successfully. but when I try to run image in my system. I am getting the below error.

**Exception  :-
main] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'tracingFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/instrument/web/TraceWebServletConfiguration$ServletConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'tracingFilter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'braveHttpServerHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/brave/instrument/web/BraveHttpBridgeConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'braveHttpServerHandler' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'httpTracing' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/brave/instrument/web/BraveHttpConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'httpTracing' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'tracing' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/brave/BraveAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'tracing' parameter 3; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultTraceSampler' defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/brave/BraveSamplerConfiguration$RefreshScopedSamplerConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class brave.sampler.Sampler: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.ClassFormatError-->Illegal class name "java/lang/Class[]" in class file brave/sampler/Sampler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3454fa76
INFO [currency-exchange,,] 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
WARN [currency-exchange,,] 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.base@15.0.1/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.base@15.0.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
java.base@15.0.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(Unknown Source)
java.base@15.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)**

Comment: I have the same problem `Illegal class name "java/lang/Class[]` in docker. Someone said it is a mac m1 chip issue and it can be solved (but I don't know how. I'm still finding). In my case, I ran jar on ubuntu image for amd64 on my mac m1.