# Issue with Spring Boot throwing "Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is a simple Spring Boot code that once I add a repository starts to fail.
It's using Spring Boot 2.6.0 with Spring Data JDBC and postgres.

This is a main service that injects another service and a repository.

```
package com.igor.myobject.scheduler;

@Service
public class PriceFetcherScheduledTask {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PriceFetcherScheduledTask.class);

    @Autowired
    private MyObjectFetcher myObjectFetcher;
    @Autowired
    private MyObjectRepository namedParameterMyObjectRepository;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void fetchMyObject() {
        final CurrencyResponse usdToBrlResponse = myObjectFetcher.fetch();

        namedParameterDolarPriceRepository.save(
                new MyObject(
                        usdToBrlResponse.getHigh(),
                        usdToBrlResponse.getLow(),
                        usdToBrlResponse.getTimestamp()
                )
        );
    }

}
```

And the repository implementation

```
package com.igor.myobject.repository;

@Repository
public class NamedParameterMyObjectRepository implements MyObjectRepository {

    @Autowired
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    public int save(MyObject myObject) {
        return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO my_object ( created_at, low, high ) VALUES (:timestamp, :low, :high)",
                new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(myObject));
    }
}
```

This is the exception I get when running this code:

```
application_1  | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'namedParameterDolarPriceRepository' defined in URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/igor/dolar/repository/NamedParameterDolarPriceRepository.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class com.igor.dolar.repository.NamedParameterDolarPriceRepository: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.ClassFormatError-->Illegal class name "java/lang/Class[]" in class file com/igor/dolar/repository/NamedParameterDolarPriceRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$de3ddb8f
application_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
application_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
application_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
application_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
application_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
application_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
application_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
application_1  |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
application_1  |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar!/:5.3.13]
application_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
application_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:719) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
application_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:401) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
application_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
application_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
application_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1279) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT]
application_1  |    at com.igor.dolar.DolarApplication.main(DolarApplication.java:15) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
application_1  |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
application_1  |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
application_1  |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
application_1  |    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
application_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
application_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
application_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
application_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
application_1  | Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class com.igor.dolar.repository.NamedParameterDolarPriceRepository: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.ClassFormatError-->Illegal class name "java/lang/Class[]" in class file com/igor/dolar/repository/NamedParameterDolarPriceRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$de3ddb8f
```

I can't see where this code could contain a "Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class" as stated in the exception.

Comment: Are you using an M1 Mac by any chance?  Seems like others are having similar issues on M1 Macs, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/68400758 .

Comment: Yes, I saw this Mac M1 java/lang/Class[] but they were on different places. I am using a Mac M1, which could be the case.